# How to write a *ngIf statement in a table in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

```
<table border = 2 border-bottom = 2>
    <th> </th>
    <th>S. No.</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Creation date</th>
    <th>Modification date</th>

    <tr *ngFor = "let checkboxesBlog of getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls; let i = index;" >
        <a *ngIf = "checkboxesBlog.controls.visible.value === true">
            <td [formGroup] = "checkboxesBlog"> 
                <input type      = "checkbox"
                 formControlName = "checkboxValue"
                 (click)         = "onCheckboxClicked( i )">
            </td>

            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.creationDate.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.modificationDate.value }}</td>
        </a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Following if clause is creating two problems above:
`<a *ngIf = "checkboxesBlog.controls.visible.value === true">`

1. The `S.R. No.` is not sequential because the i is getting updated in for loop.
2. The first column is unnecessarily too long.

What is the way to write if statements to avoid these problems?

[image]

Comment: try removing the `a` tag

Comment: can you share codes from your typescript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some HTML elements require all immediate children to be of a specific type. For example, the `<tr>` element requires `<td>` children. You can't wrap the rows in a conditional `<a>`.

**ng-container to the rescue**

The Angular `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Here's the conditional row again, this time using `<ng-container>`.

```
<table border = 2 border-bottom = 2>
    <th> </th>
    <th>S. No.</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Creation date</th>
    <th>Modification date</th>

    <tr *ngFor = "let checkboxesBlog of getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls; let i = index;" >
        <ng-container *ngIf = "checkboxesBlog.controls.visible.value === true">
            <td [formGroup] = "checkboxesBlog"> 
                <input type      = "checkbox"
                 formControlName = "checkboxValue"
                 (click)         = "onCheckboxClicked( i )">
            </td>

            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.creationDate.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.modificationDate.value }}</td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For more information: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl did this solution also solve the index issue? like now you are having 1 and 2 as Serial Number? I beleive for more rows that scenario will fail.

Comment: This solution did not help with indexing. That's true. @AakashGarg

Comment: oh ok, i thought i was missing something. thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl is the index an important part of the page? if so, unfortunately, there is no good solution on the template side. filtering must be done on the controller

Comment: Sam. Thank you. That's what the other answer has shown. That other answer has solved the problem of indexing.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go :-**

```
<table border = 2 border-bottom = 2>
    <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>S. No.</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Creation date</th>
    <th>Modification date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor = "let checkboxesBlog of filteredCheckBoxes; let i = index;" >
        <a>
            <td [formGroup] = "checkboxesBlog"> 
                <input type      = "checkbox"
                 formControlName = "checkboxValue"
                 (click)         = "onCheckboxClicked( i )">
            </td>

            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.creationDate.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ checkboxesBlog.controls.modificationDate.value }}</td>
        </a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**In Typescript :-**

```
public filteredCheckBoxes = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.filterData();
}

public filterData() {
  this.filteredCheckBoxes = this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls.filter((data) => data.controls.visible.value);
}
```

Comment: please point out the documentation for keyword 'filter' used in your answer.

Comment: Here you go @Aquarius_Girl  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: That's why I could not find it. I was looking in Angular documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62014605/462608, throws the following error:

`Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

from the following function:

```
public filterData() {
  this.filteredCheckBoxes = this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls.filter((data) => data.controls.visible.value);
}
```

Way to solve that error is to use `data.get('visible').value` instead of `data.controls.visible.value` as follows:

```
this.filteredCheckBoxes = this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls.filter( (data) => data.get('visible').value) );
```